# Using jquery to auto populate only a time input & not other buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use jquery to auto populate an input time field. It works fine; but it applies the time to my other button. How do I only refer it to my input type time field?

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks

HTML

```
<input type="time" value="" />
<input type="button" value=""/>
```

jquery

```
$("input").val( "17:39:57" );
```

Comment: **$("input[type=time]").val( "17:39:57" );**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [attribute equal selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("input[type=time]").val( "17:39:57" );
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vb1szd8n/3/)**